# Make several .ajax calls on the same page fire in order

Tags: jquery

I have several jQuery .ajax calls on the same page like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page1.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        //do some stuff with returned html
    }
});
```

When I run the page some may complete out of order.  I'm guessing they are all starting at the same time.

Is there a way for me to queue them up so they fire in a particular order and not until the previous one completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/) which allows you to queue requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain them, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page1.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        //do some stuff with returned html
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        // do your next call
    }
});
```

Wait for the first to complete, and then make your next one. A better approach though is to do it like this:

```
var waiting = 0;

// for each request:
waiting++;
$.ajax({
    url: "page1.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        // save the returned stuff in an array
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        if (--waiting <=0) { // == would probably suffice, but i like to be safe.
          //process the result
        }
    }
});
```

This reduces the load time, and allows you to process it in order.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to go with the plugin just to make life a little easier for me.

Comment: I was wholly unaware that $.ajax had parameter `cache` it seemed more like implementation I should do, not jquery. Got me for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in the way you write your code. By making the next AJAX call in the callback function of the first you could *chain* requests:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page1.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        // Make another call here
        $.ajax({
            url: "page1.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                // and so on
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to go with the plugin just to make life a little easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

[AjaxQueue](http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue) plugin to the rescue!